# Copy datagridview cell content to clipboard in FullRowSelect Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform datagridview to show customer details and it has a context menu. And I have set the datagridview selection Mode to "FullRowSelect". 
What i want is i want to copy the content of the clicked cell content to the clipboard. Not the whole row content. Just the cell content.

I have used the following code to show the Context Menu when it right click on the datagridview and select the row.

```
private void dgvCusList_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                DataGridViewCell clickedCell = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

                this.dgvCusList.CurrentCell = clickedCell;  

                var relativeMousePosition = dgvCusList.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

                this.cnxtMnuCusResult.Show(dgvCusList, relativeMousePosition);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to copy the the cell content to clipboard when i click copy menu item in my context menu.
Please help me to solove this matter.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I think you should post the code with the `Clipboard.SetText` and not the code to open your context menu strip.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are having the `SelectionMode` property as `FullRowSelect` then copy functionality of `DataGridView` will copy the entire row. Change the value to `CellSelect`. Set the below properties to copy only the cell content.

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

If you want to retain the `FullRowSelect` selection mode, then do like below..

```
 void contextMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Copy" && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
        {
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(), false);
        }
    }

 void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = myDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        }
    }
```

Comment: It says "Vote up requires 15 reputations". I think its becoz i am new. I hv only 6 reputations.

Comment: @DilnuwanChathuranga - but you could accept the answer

Comment: Must include ClipboardCopyMode = Disable for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

In contextMenu or CellDoubleClick Event or cellMouseClick event , you can do the following

```
Clipboard.SetText(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

It will copy the particular cell's Content

Answer (score 0):

Junaith's answer does not work like it should when 'EditMode' = EditOnEnter; it only really works when it is set to EditProgrammatically. An additional step then may be for some, to replace the default menu with your own.  You can disable the default menu:

(In VB)

```
Private Sub DG1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DG1.EditingControlShowing

        DirectCast(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl).ShortcutsEnabled = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

most easy solution:
add CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit event to control ClipboardCopyMode.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) 
    { 
     this.dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.Disable; 
    } 

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
    { 
     this.dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText; 
    }
```