# Copy datagridview current cell content to clipbord when SelectionMode=FullRowSelect?

Tags: powershell, datagridview, copy-paste

I'm using a `DataGridView` with the property `.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect` for some reason.

I also wish to copy cell content to paste it somewhere else in the DGV. Unfortunately, the selection mode seems to force the `Ctrl+C` to copy the whole row.

Is there a way to configure it to take the current cell content with `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: I saw a similar post in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527646/copy-datagridview-cell-content-to-clipboard-in-fullrowselect-mode) but I'm not familiar enough to do the translation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO has rules --- [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I get it. I'll take some time to do some example.

Comment: No worreis, but PS can use C# code and vice versa. The pointer you have gives you guidance, but if you want a cell, then you have to ask for a cell. Just search for [powershell DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score 0):

One of the SO Q&A's from the search links provided, shows how to work with cells.

[Powershell datagridview cell click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284508/powershell-datagridview-cell-click-event)

```
function gridClick()
{
    $rowIndex    = $myGrid.CurrentRow.Index
    $columnIndex = $myGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

    Write-Host $rowIndex
    Write-Host $columnIndex 
    Write-Host $myGrid.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[0].value
    Write-Host $myGrid.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex].value
}
```

Now this is not the copy-paste step you are trying but should give you the direction you need to target cell data.